# Python cannot find file to send as email attachment

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-upload, email-attachments, mime-message

I am using Python3 and mime.multipart to send an attachment. I was able to send attachment successfully. But today, I get an error saying file does not exist, when I can see in WINSCP that it clearly does. Is this a permissions issue? Also when I list the contents of the directory, the file DOES NOT show up. What is going on?

Comment: I'm going to state the obvious checks: either the directory python is looking in has changed (check), or the file has moved (check)

Comment: The other files in the same folder with the same permissions get listed, but not the one I want to attach. Pasting some debug statements: >>Writing to /home/user/programs/automation/files/Acme_Insights.xslx >>in files directory..(glob.glob)
['/home/user/programs/automation/files/test.txt'] (acme didnt get listed) >>File "process_insights_python.py", line 885, in main
    fp = open(fileToSend, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/home/user/programs/automation/files/Acme_Insights.xslx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't closing the stream after writing to the file. So the code couldn't find the file. However when the script finished, the stream would get closed by force and I would see the file in the folder.